# Why is this HTTP request continually looping?

Tags: php, session, cookies, kohana, kohana-3

I'm probably overlooking something really obvious here.

Comments are in to help explain any library specific code.

```
public function areCookiesEnabled() {

        $random = 'cx67ds';

        // set cookie
        cookie::set('test_cookie', $random);

        // try and get cookie, if not set to false
        $testCookie = cookie::get('test_cookie', false);


        $cookiesAppend = '?cookies=false';

        // were we able to get the cookie equal ?
        $cookiesEnabled = ($testCookie === $random);

        // if $_GET['cookies'] === false , etc try and remove $_GET portion
        if ($this->input->get('cookies', false) === 'false' AND $cookiesEnabled) {
          url::redirect(str_replace($cookiesAppend, '', url::current())); // redirect 
          return false;
        }

        // all else fails, add a $_GET[]
        if ( ! $cookiesEnabled) {

          url::redirect(url::current().$cookiesAppend);
        }

        return $cookiesEnabled;

    }
```

Firstly, I wanted an easy way to check if cookies were enabled. I achieved this, but in the event of no cookies, there was an ugly `?cookies=false` in the URL.

That was OK, but then if you reloaded the page and did have cookies enabled again, I wanted to redirect the user so it stripped off `?cookies=false` in the URL (allowing the method to recheck and learn that cookies now *are* enabled.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `$cookiesEnabled = ($testCookie === $random);`, there are 4 cases:

1. `$cookiesEnabled` is true and `$_GET['cookies'] === 'false'` is true
2. `$cookiesEnabled` is true and `$_GET['cookies'] === 'false'` is false
3. `$cookiesEnabled` is false and `$_GET['cookies'] === 'false'` is true
4. `$cookiesEnabled` is false and `$_GET['cookies'] === 'false'` is false

Case 1 is handled by the first `if` block.  The `return` statement is intended to handle cases 2 and 3; the second `if` block is intended to handle only case 4, but it catches both case 3 and 4.  In case 3, the URL already has `?cookies=false`, but since `$cookiesEnabled` is false, we redirect to add `?cookies=false`, and cycle back into case 3.

Answer (score 0):

You must be leaving something out since there *is* no loop in that code. If you meant that the *browser* is looping (e.g. getting continuous redirects), then I recommend installing the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) extension to Firefox and watch what the browser and server are actually saying to each other. Putting in some logging code in the snippet above might also be instructive.

**Update for comment:**

Then I really recommend putting in print statements inside the `if`s so you can see which ones you're going through and what the various values are. Clearly *something* is not getting set the way you thought it would be, so now you need to find out what it actually is.

One thing I have encountered several times is that the code itself is OK, but there is a .htaccess file that is working against you, so go double check any .htaccess files in any of the directories, starting from DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. I do have Live HTTP Headers, but I am not sure what I should change to get it to stop. It seems it is requesting, and every time is being made to redirect again (when cookies are disabled).